# Extracting values from indices without using loops

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

So I have one matrix containing the data and a vector containing information on which data I should extract from the matrix. The real matrix is much longer but below is a short version just to illustrate what I meant.

```
Data matrix = array([[1 2 3],[0 3 5],[1 4 4]]) 
Info vector = array([[1], [0], [2]])
Answer matrix = array([[2 (the second element)], [0(the first element)], 4(the third element)]])
```

Simple for loop:

```
length_data = data.shapes[0]
for i in xrange(length_data)
    answer[i] = data[info[i],i]
```

I know how I can do this with a simple for loop, but how do I accomplish this using vectorization, without the usage of any loops?

Thanks!

Slight addition to the question: What if I want the answer to be as follows

```
Answer matrix = array([[0 2 0], [0 0 0], [0 0 4]])
```

Comment: What does your matrix actually look like? Is it a custom data structure, or is it just a list of lists/ a 2D array?

Comment: if its a list you can do `list.indexof(item)`

Comment: Why would you not use a loop? That is the only way, no?

Comment: I guess you could use the `map` function, but I personally wouldn't.

Comment: The matrix is just a 2D array. (I suppose you meant the data matrix)

Comment: @mystery578 See below for a solution without `for` loops.

Comment: What does "using vectorization" mean in this context?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi ok! trying it now!

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct language? what is  `[1 2 3; 0 3 5; 1 4 4]` supposed to be? Or `[1; 0; 2]`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have no idea...that's just what was said in the question of my assignment

Comment: Maybe you could look up the Vectorization section in your textbook (or the teacher's handouts, or whatever) and let us know?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi can I operate/broadcast the result I get from zip with other vectors/matrices?

Comment: are you sure this is python?

Comment: @mystery578.You need to add  your *simple for loop* because your input data does not look anything like python but if it is you sound like you have numpy arrays which is a lot different to regular python lists

Comment: the syntax doesn't appear to be python. "vectorization" in python, at least in the sense I'm familiar with the term, could only be achieved through libraries such as numpy, and not in vanilla python.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have provided the for loop in question, and corrected some of my code. hope it makes things clearer!

Comment: @mystery578, you have numpy arrays, you should tag the question with numpy as all the answers here will mean you no longer have a numpy array. Worse again they will cause errors, `__getitem__` ->  `descriptor '__getitem__' requires a 'list' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `zip` the two lists together like so to index the first list by the other.

```
answer = map(lambda x: x[0][x[1]], zip(data, info)) # [2, 0, 4]
```

Comment: `data = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 5], [1, 4, 4]]` and `info = [1, 0, 2]`

Comment: Wouldn't the loop you originally had be faster (not to mention clearer) than this `map(lambda...)` anyway? I'm honestly not sure why we're avoiding loops here, and I'm unclear on what a "vectorization" of this problem would entail.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Probably, but he said without a for loop. Whatever.

Comment: yup, solved it with the zip function. thank you!!! helped me learned a new function in python!

Comment: Anytime. Hope you come to understand Python to it full extent and enjoy it.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> data = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 5], [1, 4, 4]]
>>> info = [1, 0, 2]
>>> map(list.__getitem__, data, info)
[2, 0, 4]
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? That's the 100% straight-forward answer, and as demonstrated it works.

Comment: Technically you end up with a `map` object, but if you wrap it in `list()` it provides a `list` with the desired output. I'm not sure why this was downvoted (forgetting a `list()` call isn't sufficient reason), but it works and it's quite tidy.

Comment: Nah, I didn't forget `list`. I simply used Python 2, where `map` does return a list. I do that sometimes to show the actual solution more clearly.

Comment: @StefanPochmann +1 for the clever answer. I went with a `lambda` and a `zip` but this is much better.

Comment: Then this answer has no problems in the context of the given question.

Comment: quick point on the list created. can I sum it with a vector/matrix?

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean by a vector or matrix, because Python does not have built-in data types by those names to my knowledge.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 A three dimensional vector in math is a list of three components in a pair of brackets. I think he just wants to add the X, Y, and  Z components.

Comment: That describes a vector in math (or `numpy`, apparently), but not in pure Python, which was the mystery in this question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You mean the *mystery578* in this question.

Comment: @mystery578 If you want something like `[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]` to result in `[5,7,9]`, then you should have a look at numpy.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Easily done in pure python: `[a + b for a, b in zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])]`. I say close the question as unclear at this point.

Comment: Stefan, @Padraic figured out that the OP is already using `numpy` and simply neglected to mention it.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Thanks. I do like this better than your current solution as well, but like Tigerhawk I liked the comprehension (and I don't think the ban on "loops" applies to comprehensions).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Oh, ok. Boring then.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Yeah, of course it's easy to do yourself, but it's ugly and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed your data is more likely `numpy` arrays or you have `numpy` installed, then it can be achieved by using `np.choose`:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[0, 3, 5],[1, 4, 4]])

In [5]: vector = np.array([[1], [0], [2]])

In [6]: np.choose(vector.flat, matrix.T)
Out[6]: array([2, 0, 4])
```

> choose(a, choices, out=None, mode='raise')
>       Construct an array from an index array and a set of arrays to choose from.

Using `vector.flat` to get iterator of `[1, 0, 2]`; `matrix.T` to get a transpose view of the current `matrix`, `np.choose` will use `vector` as an index array.

Although the fact that using `choose` will still iterate over `vector` array.

Comment: The professor is probably expecting a `numpy`-oriented answer like this one.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, unfortunately everyone has provided good answers with straight Python and we all knew until the very end it was `numpy`. But cheers anyway :-)

Comment: I didn't know it was `numpy`, as I've never used that library. :(

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, may well start hacking into `numpy`, I'm no expert neither but it is very powerful and convenient to deal with bulk numeric data/array/matrix etc. Mind asking what's your domain, web dev?

Comment: I'm in technical writing.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, good for you! I am pretty lame on writing in general. I'm on web/software dev btw, mainly in python/pandas

Answer (score 1):

Numpy allows you to index with lists or arrays, so you just need to use `data[i, info]` where `i` is the whole range, not just one element, from your loop and `info` is a 1d array.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 5], [1, 4, 4]])
info = np.array([1, 0, 2])

i = np.arange(data.shape[0])
print(data[i, info])
# array([2, 0, 4])
```

It's hard to tell from your question because you didn't actually post working code, but it looks like your info array might have shape (3, 1) instead of (3,). In that case you just need to add a `ravel`:

```
print(data[i, info.ravel()])
# array([2, 0, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

No loops? Okay, no loops.

```
>>> m = [[1,2,3], [0,3,5], [1,4,4]]
>>> v = [1,0,2]
>>> def match(a, b):
...     return match_core([], iter(a), iter(b))
...
>>> def match_core(l, a, b):
...     l.append(next(a)[next(b)])
...     try:
...         return match_core(l, a, b)
...     except StopIteration:
...         return l
...
>>> match(m, v)
[2, 0, 4]
```